# Android New App Version Breaking Changes Store Filtering

Tags: android

Lets say version 1 of the app is out in the wild for some time and accumulates X users.

Version 2 comes as an update, however starts to use new features (eg GPS).

Lets say 5% of X users do not have GPS on their device. What happens to them when an update (version 2) is rolled out? Do they just not get the update and continue using the old version?

Would they still see Version 1 in the store or completely nothing after the update?

Also does version 1 continue to be visible to new users without GPS or is the app completely hidden from them in the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens to them when an update (version 2) is rolled out? Do they just not get the update and continue using the old version?

Device which dont have GPS hardware, those won't get update (version 2) of your app.

> Would they still see Version 1 in the store or completely nothing after the update?

No, Now app will no longer be visible, you will see an error message something like when  you try to search "Your device is not compatible".

> Also does version 1 continue to be visible to new users without GPS or is the app completely hidden from them in the store?

Yes, it will be no longer on play store after you release version 2 of it.

### How you should handle this problem :-

You should use `uses-feature` tag for this like below so that device which do not have GPS still user can run your app on it and Google Play will list your app as well but wherever you are trying to fetch location. There you have to check whether device has GPS hardware or not.

> ```
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.LOCATION" android:required="false" />
> ```